# How to get jquery switchClass working in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I want to use the jquery "switchClass" in a Drupal 7 Website. I already got the jquery accordion and tabs working, by adding the library in this way:

drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tabs');

drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');

Now i'm trying to get switchClass working this way:

drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.switchClass');

... which is not working.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you for helping!

Lars

Answer (score 1):

`switchclass()` isn't a library, it's a function that's part of UI Effects. So...

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'effects');
```

Should then let you use:

```
$('.foo').switchClass('foo', 'bar', 1000);
```